# Can I load all entities from a file in one go?

Tags: fiware-orion

I have a file with a list of entities in JSON format:

```
[
 {
  "id": "IST-AFRICA-2018_Sensor6",
  "type": "Device",
  "TC": {
    "type": "Sensor",
    "value": 24.26,
    "metadata": {
...
```

I can I add them all in one go in Orion?

I tried:

```
curl -v localhost:1026/v2/op/update -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service:waziup' -d '{ "actionType": "APPEND", "entities": `cat file.json`}"
```

But without success.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Which error does curl report?

Comment: @fgalan: it's `{"error":"ParseError","description":"Errors found in incoming JSON buffer"}`. I think the shell doesn't perform the replacement of the `cat file.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
jq -c -r '.[]' entities.json | while read i; do
   echo "inserting $i"
   echo $i | curl -X POST "http://localhost:1026/v2/entities" -s -S --header 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @-
done
```

Comment: I'm not entirely satisfied with the solution, because it doesn't keep dateCreated and dataModified, which I use in my application...

Comment: I think that deserves a separate question to be able to provide a proper answer to it. Could you create a separate question post, please? Thx!

Comment: @fgalan: I edited this question to mention the problem with dateCreated and dateModified: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202536/fiware-orion-change-entity-type. As those two questions are very related, I didn't wanted to create a third.